# Runtime.exec("echo 2") gives error=13, but why?

Tags: java, linux, shell, permissions

I try to run commands using Java. This is the class:

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/echo 2");
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
[grim@obelix  dev.xxx /mnt/ramdisk/workspace/test]$ /usr/bin/echo 2
2
[grim@obelix  dev.xxx /mnt/ramdisk/workspace/test]$ /mnt/ramdisk/apache-maven-3.8.5/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=test.Test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------------< test:test >------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) @ test ---
[WARNING] 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/echo": error=13, Keine Berechtigung
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1142)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:591)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:415)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:312)
    at test.Test.main (Test.java:8)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Keine Berechtigung
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init> (ProcessImpl.java:313)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start (ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1109)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:591)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:415)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:312)
    at test.Test.main (Test.java:8)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:832)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.029 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-27T11:39:28+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) on project test: An exception occured while executing the Java class. Cannot run program "/usr/bin/echo": error=13, Keine Berechtigung -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[grim@obelix 1 dev.xxx /mnt/ramdisk/workspace/test]$
```

How to solve the Exception?

Comment: `Keine Berechtigung` means `Permission denied`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that the library

```
/mnt/ramdisk/jdk-15.0.2/lib/jspawnhelper/jspawnhelper
```

did not had execution permissions. After I added execution permissions the code worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ ls /usr/bin/echo 
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/echo': No such file or directory
goose@t410:/tmp$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
goose@t410:/tmp$ /bin/bash -c "echo 2"
2
goose@t410:/tmp$
```

Your arguments to `Runtime.exec` should be the last ones above

Comment: your echo is store somewhere else. Try `which echo` to find out where your echo is stored.

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash": error=13, Keine Berechtigung`

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls": error=13, Keine Berechtigung`

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "type": error=13, Keine Berechtigung`

Comment: I told you your suggestions are nonsense.

Comment: I'm confused - you asked the question and you're commenting on it as if you're a different person...?

Comment: Idk. Id comment my own question to add the translation of `Keine Berechtigung`. Is it offense?

Comment: I'm talking about comments like this: *your echo is store somewhere else. Try which echo to find out where your echo is stored.*

Comment: Ah I did a spelling mistake, I meant "stored" not "store". So the sentence must be "your `echo` is stored somewhere else. Try `which echo` to find out where your `echo` is stored. "

Comment: I repeat my question: why are you answering your own question?

Comment: Oh did I? I am confused, sorry. My problem remains unchanged. What I have noticed is that I have a program located at `/usr/bin/echo`, this file does realy exits, this program does realy work (like you can see in the first and second line of the result in the question) but using java it throws a Exception. I have no clue about the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243386/discussion-between-g00se-and-grim).